# Is glow in the dark paint suitable for creative usage?

Tags: paint

I came across the notion of a Light/UV -sensitive background, to perform temporary creative photographic effects. This seems to be a paper/cloth impregnated with a Light/UV sensitive coating, that glows in the dark/changes colour according to exposure to light.

I was thinking that i could accomplish something like this with glow in the dark wall paint, or something of the sort, sacrificing one portion of a wall in my house, or some wood panels (like canvases).

My problem is that i do not have much experience with glow in the dark paint (brands, name of what i want, prices, durability, etc), or even know if glow in the dark paint is what i want.

Comment: This might be a better fit on [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/). But I'm not familiar with their community, so maybe not.

Comment: Glow in the dark paint isn't commonly used in home improvement projects.  As such you're not likely to run across people who can answer it.   I'd rephrase it to make it more about making your own backdrops, and the effect you are going for, and try it out on photography.  (A photo of the effect you want always helps out there)

Comment: I thought about it, but this is definitely a DIY thing. it's the paint and its prices/properties that i'm interested in...maybe some SE website about art/painting?

Comment: Hello. Moderator from PhotoSE. If the question here really is about the paints, it may or may not be a fit for our site. If you don't get any answers here, you could try migrating it to the Photography site. Just beware, we may close it there if it doesn't get any answers or people don't think its a good fit.

Comment: @jrista Thanks for having a look. I'll see if we can get it a bit more on topic for photography before migrating.

Comment: @JoséNunoFerreira, If this is about creating a backdrop, can you edit it to make that detail more clear before we try migrating it? This looks OT for DIY since it's about a hobby project rather than more traditional home maintenance and repair.